# Want to compare delta files recursively using rsync when I have file list in left in text file and Folder at right hand

Tags: file, compare, rsync

I have a list of files mentioned at left hand side in a text file and I have a separate folder where I have list of physical files. I have to compare the left hand's FileList.txt with Right hand's Directory files(Recursively) and copy delta part using rsync. I am using the below command but not getting any files to copy.

Below is the dry run attempt .

rsync -rvnc --include-from=/cygdrive/c/Users/SG066221/Desktop/scripts/diff_Lib_WITH_EMPLTY.txt /cygdrive/c/Users/SG066221/Desktop/scripts/FROM_LIST_2_ANOTHER/   1>C:\Users\SG066221\Desktop\scripts\diff_FINAL.txt

Output is :

sending incremental file list
drwx------              0 2018/11/12 14:26:18 .

sent 38 bytes  received 64 bytes  204.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for rsync is:

```
rsync <options> <include> <exclude> src/ dest/
```

Your problems:

- If you only list one directory, nothing will happen.
- If you have includes without excludes then it'll include everything.
- (You have dry-run set, but you probably knew that.)

Try this:

```
rsync -rvc --include-from=file.txt --exclude='*' src/ dest/
```

Make sure that `file.txt` contains only the filenames *within* `src/` (i.e. with "src/" stripped off). Make sure that any sub-directories you want files copied from are listed too, on their own line (alternatively, add `--include='*/'` *before* the exclude).

What it says is, copy from `src` to `dest`, including files in `file.txt`, and excluding everything else.